# Can you Stop Viking Raiders with Conversion?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Viking raiders are pests! It's easy enough to beat them or scare them off, but can I eliminate the problem by converting them? Will Catholic Vikings continue raiding other Catholics? Or do I have to seek other ways to eliminate their raiding?

Comment: So this raises the question whether there are any other ways to stop Viking raiders. Any takers? Anything besides the occupation and conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only pagans are allowed to raid. Converting them would solve the issue.

The question would be how you plan on converting them. Sending your court chaplain to try to convert them is generally just a good way to get him thrown in a cold dungeon somewhere in Scandinavia. The only way to do it efficiently would be to seize control of the territory yourself, and then the problem goes away anyways.

All in all, it's probably more trouble than it's worth. The AI generally sends groups of raiders too small to be much of a threat or to do much economic damage. They are pesky, but I'd say your time is better spent on other things.

Comment: "good way to get him thrown in a cold dungeon" - exactly! Conversions to stop raiding are a minor benefit to getting rid of troublesome vassals!

Comment: That is a great idea. "Count ProblemGuy, I'm so impressed with your faith that I'm making you my court chaplain and sending you off to convert the infidels!"

Comment: Ah, one of the great things about CK2: One player's "Unfortunately..." is another player's "Sounds great! Where do I sign?"

Comment: Actually did this playing as a Muslim. When I, as the Sultan, died my son, an Emir, inherited everything. As the new Sultan I was stuck with the Emir's Court Imam, who had a mere 11 Learning, compared to the Sultan's old Imam with a 26. So, the Imam was sent to convert a Tengri High Chief and wound up imprisoned in under a week. And so the old Imam gets his position back very fast. It's good to be the Sultan.

Answer (score -1):

another solution: Coast guard - take a look http://s13.postimg.org/q1700qpad/coast_guard.png

Comment: I don't think that this is a viable solution. When these troops are your personal levy, it would cost you more in a month than a raid would cost you. When these troops are from your vassals, they will soon get very angry at you.